# jq JSON handle missing fields

Tags: json, jq

Normally, I want to do something like this, which works:

```sh
echo '{"a": 123, "b": "{\"embedded\": 456}", "c": 789}' | jq '{a, "b2": .b | fromjson, c}'
```

that works and yields:

```json
{
  "a": 123,
  "b2": {
    "embedded": 456
  },
  "c": 789
}
```

Sometimes, field "b" is missing and in that case the above jq will error:

```sh
echo '{"a": 123, "c": 789}' | jq '{a, "b2": .b | fromjson, c}'
```

That gives a null error, which makes sense because b is missing so `.b` is null and `fromjson` errors on null. I want to write my `jq` command so if `b` is missing for a record, then it isn't output. I want to simply get this:

```json
{
  "a": 123,
  "c": 789
}
```

I've skimmed through the `jq` Reference manual. I'm having trouble getting the if/else/end construct to solve this. I don't see any other null handling functions or language constructs available.

Comment: Note that the initial `. |' is never needed and is usually best omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like below. Use the if condition to check against the presence of `.b` to be `null`. Form the structure to have all fields when not null.

```
jq 'if .b != null then { a, "b2":(.b|fromjson), c } else {a, c} end'
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible approaches, each with variants.  Here are illustrations of a constructive approach, and a postprocessing one.

#### Constructive

```
{a} + ((select(has("b")) | {"b2": .b | fromjson}) // {}) + {c}
```

or more concisely but with slightly different semantics:

```
[{a}, (select(.b) | {b2: .b | fromjson}), {c}] | add
```

#### Postprocessing

```
{a, "b2": (.b | fromjson? // null), c}
| if .b2 == null then del(.b2) else . end
```

Comment: For the constructive approach I think another variation is `({"b2": (try(.b) | fromjson) } // {})`.

Comment: `echo '{"a": 123, "c": 789}' | jq '{a, c} + (select(has("b")) | {"b2": .b | fromjson})'` produces no output.

Answer (score 0):

This works the best, combining suggestions from peak and Inian's answers:

```sh
# example with b
echo '{"a": 123, "b": "{\"embedded\": 456}", "c": 789}' | jq '{a, c} + if has("b") then {"b": .b | fromjson} else {} end'

# example without b
echo '{"a": 123, "not_b": "{\"embedded\": 456}", "c": 789}' | jq '{a, c} + if has("b") then {"b": .b | fromjson} else {} end'
```